# Ubuntu in VirtualBox does not start after restart and shows weird pixelated screen

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I installed [Ubuntu 16.04.1](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) on VirtualBox. I logged in, installed VirtualBox additions and restarted the system. The system did not load again, instead I see this:

[image: image description]

The aspect ratio of the image is preserved in this screenshot and it doesn't make much sense to me - no screen has such dimensions. I did not do anything else special that I could mention. This is the only thing I see before the screenshot above:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As memory serves me, switching TTY's should fix the problem.

In your case, I can't see what your HOST key is set for, so please take note. To fix your video problem, hit the  <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, followed by <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. It's a bug.

On a Mac, you may have to <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

For the journal errors... check your file system...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` *(or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`)*
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: It fixed the problem, but could you explain what happened?

Comment: The video problem is a long standing bug. The journal problem was some disk corruption.

Comment: And what does the F1/F7 combo do?

Comment: Ubuntu has 6 text terminals, and one (or more) graphic terminals. My commands force a switch to the first text terminal, and then a switch back to the graphic terminal. It works around the bug. You may never see the problem again, or if you do, now you know how to get around it.